# Factor and labels on tibble

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to process data using value labels. 
I have simple CSV:
"var"
"A1" 
"A2"
...

When I import data with `read.csv`, and use `factor()` data are stored correctly.

```r
test <- read.csv("test.csv", sep="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
test$new <- factor(test[, 1], levels=c("A1","A2","A3"),labels=c("yes", "no", "don't know"))
```

dput returns:

```r
structure(list(Var = c("A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A2"), new = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("yes", "no", "don't know"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

But when I try the same with `readr::read_csv()` my Var column is re-coded to NA.

```r
test2 <- read_csv("test.csv")
test2$new <- factor(test2[, 1], levels=c("A1","A2","A3"),labels=c("yes", "no", "don't know"))
```

dput() returns:

```r
structure(list(Var = c("A1", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A2"), new = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), class = "factor", .Label = c("yes", "no", "don't know"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Var = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried also `parse_factor()` function from `readr::read_csv` but this function doesn't support labels, as it is done with `factor()`. 
So how to use `factor()` with tibble object, or is there any other simple solution to add value labels to tibble?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the actual structure of the `new` df1 column you will see that the "levels" are gone and that only the "labels" remain:

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(cc = c("A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", 
"A3", "A1", "A2", "A2"), new = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("yes", "no", "don't know"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

So trying to do anything using the `factor` function that depends on the original character values for that second column (regardless of whether it is a tibble or not) will fail. It would have failed with the original `df1` before you coerced it to a tibble.